# Empirical distribution function converges against $N(0,1)$ in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $(X_k)_{k \ge 1}$ be a family of i.i.d. random variables and $F$ be their distribution function. The empirical distribution function is defined as

$F_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{X_k \le t} \ $   for $t \in \mathbb R$.

Now I want to show that, for $t \in \mathbb R$ and $0 < F(t) < 1$, we have that

$$\sqrt n \frac{F_n(t) - F(t)}{\sqrt {F(t) (1 - F(t)}} \rightarrow_d N(0,1).$$

I'm pretty sure that this works by using the CLT. I already now that $E(F_n(t)) = F(t)$ and $Var(F_n(t)) = \frac{F(t)(1-F(t))}{n}.$

So the term on the left nearly has the form that I need to simply state that it, by the CLT, converges pointwise against the density function of $N(0,1)$, which is equivalent to the convergence in distribution from above. But I don't see how to do this exactly.

Comment: For fixed $t$, the quantity $nF_n(t)$ has the binomial distribution   with parameters $n$ and $F(t)$.

Comment: What do you mean the left "nearly" has the form you need to apply the CLT? It is exactly what you need. Could you perhaps state the form of the CLT you are trying to use?

Comment: For $S_n$ being a sum of random variables, $\mu$ the expected value and $\sigma^2$ the variance, the central theorem works with $\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n}$. That's the way I learned it.

Comment: @kimchilover: You're right! That was part of the excercise too. So I have to use that, I guess.